# Where does the phrase Ichikabachika (一か八か) come from?

Tags: numbers, phrases

According to the Japanese dictionary, it means "sink or swim", "do or die", or "high stakes", but I can't figure out the etymology.

The literal meaning appears to be "one or eight". So does it literally mean "the odds are 1 to 8"?

Comment: See also: http://gogen-allguide.com/i/ichikabachika.html - it looks like it doesn't actually have anything to do with 一 or 八, and means something more like 50-50 odds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shogakukan's *Kokugo Dai Jiten Dictionary* states:

> カルタ賭博から出た語
>     A term from card gambling

The entry also gives 一{いち}か六{ろく}か as a synonym.  This version may be more obviously related to dice gambling, but as mentioned in the discussion at http://gogen-allguide.com/i/ichikabachika.html, the 一 and 八 (or 六) here may not directly indicate the numbers, and might instead be slang or jargon for [odds or evens](https://www.google.com/search?q=gambling+%22odds+or+evens%22).  Shogakukan's definition of "choosing one of two choices" seems to back this up, and the additional definition of "leaving one's luck to fate and bravely doing something" and additional synonym of 伸{の}るか反{そ}るか suggests a kind of "all or nothing" implication.

So ultimately, this doesn't have to do with "one to eight odds", and instead 一か八か indicates a 50-50 all-or-nothing gamble.